# Looking for this hard copy comic book series

Tags: story-identification, comics, aliens

He's the descendant of an advanced alien race that gets exterminated through a war and is left on planet Earth in the pre medieval times. Fearsome with the sword and his bow. In on of the books one of his enemies is filled with small spiders that comes out after he kills him.

Comment: When did you read this? When might it have been published? Can you remember the names of any of the characters? Locations?

Comment: Black & White or color? What language? Do you recall if it ever crossed over with other franchises/characters? Was it geared towards/away from any age group? Do you remember anything about the covers?